# The pop-up side menu does not display correctly at low screen heights

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a pop-up side menu

Everything looks good on full page

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4yX0.png)

But when the screen height is too small (this is the case with horizontal screens of mobile devices), then everything will be displayed incorrectly

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWr0B.png)

How can I fix this?

For screen width in css I always use say `@media screen and (max-width: 767px)`, but I haven’t seen this used for height

I think that I need to make sure that when the screen height is too small and the links go under the footer, then simply hide the footer itself and reduce the text size, but what is the best way to do this?

```js
let menuGeneral = $('#menu-general');

$('#menu-up-control').click(function () {
    $('.wrapper-main').css('opacity', '0.7');

    if ($(document).width() > 767) {
        menuGeneral.animate({ right: '0' }, 500);
    } else {
        menuGeneral.animate({ right: '0' }, 500);
    }
});

$('#menu-up-control-close').click(function () {
    $('.wrapper-main').css('opacity', '1');

    if ($(document).width() > 767) {
        menuGeneral.animate({ right: '-400px' }, 500);
    } else {
        menuGeneral.animate({ right: '-100vw' }, 500);
    }
});
```

```css
.menu-up-control {
  float:right;
  font-size:26px;
  top:3px;
  position:relative;
  cursor:pointer;
  padding:10px 100px 0 0;
}

.menu-up-control-close {
  width:15px;
}

.menu-up-control-close i {
  color:white;
  font-size:40px;
  top:3px;
  position:relative;
  cursor:pointer;
  padding:10px 0px;
  margin:50px 0 0 40px;
}

.menu-general {
  position:fixed;
  width:400px;
  top:0;
  right:-400px;
  bottom:0;
  z-index:9999;
  background-color:black;

  @media screen and (max-width: 767px){
    width: 100vw;
    right: -100vw;
  }
}

.menu-general .menu-footer {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 40px;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    padding: 40px 0 40px 60px;
    background: violet;
}

.menu-main li, .menu-main li a {
  font-size:36px;
  font-weight:700;
}
.menu-main li {
    margin: 0 0 15px;
}
.menu-main li a {
  font-weight:bold;
  color:white;
  text-decoration:none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>  
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"  type='text/css'>

</head>
<body>

  <a id="menu-up-control" class="menu-up-control">
      <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </a>

  <div id="menu-general" class="menu-general">
      <div id="menu-up-control-close" class="menu-up-control-close">
          <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
      </div>
      <ul class="menu-main">
          <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="menu-footer">
        <div class="item">Footer</div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Media query can be used for `height` as well, not just `width`.

I suggest that below the height (with the media query) in question (`450px`) you `position` the `.menu-footer` to `relative`, so it remains at the bottom, and then add an `overflow-y` `scroll` to the container, in order for the content inside to fit, like so:

```js
let menuGeneral = $('#menu-general');

$('#menu-up-control').click(function() {
  $('.wrapper-main').css('opacity', '0.7');

  if ($(document).width() > 767) {
    menuGeneral.animate({
      right: '0'
    }, 500);
  } else {
    menuGeneral.animate({
      right: '0'
    }, 500);
  }
});

$('#menu-up-control-close').click(function() {
  $('.wrapper-main').css('opacity', '1');

  if ($(document).width() > 767) {
    menuGeneral.animate({
      right: '-400px'
    }, 500);
  } else {
    menuGeneral.animate({
      right: '-100vw'
    }, 500);
  }
});
```

```css
.menu-up-control {
  float: right;
  font-size: 26px;
  top: 3px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px 100px 0 0;
}

.menu-up-control-close {
  width: 15px;
}

.menu-up-control-close i {
  color: white;
  font-size: 40px;
  top: 3px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px 0px;
  margin: 50px 0 0 40px;
}

.menu-general {
  position: fixed;
  width: 400px;
  top: 0;
  right: -400px;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
  background-color: black;
  @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    width: 100vw;
    right: -100vw;
  }
}

.menu-general .menu-footer {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 40px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 40px 0 40px 60px;
  background: violet;
}

.menu-main li,
.menu-main li a {
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.menu-main li {
  margin: 0 0 15px;
}

.menu-main li a {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/*new code from here:*/

@media (max-height: 450px) {
  #menu-general {
    overflow-y: scroll;
  }
  .menu-general .menu-footer {
    position: relative;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" type='text/css'>

</head>

<body>

  <a id="menu-up-control" class="menu-up-control">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </a>

  <div id="menu-general" class="menu-general">
    <div id="menu-up-control-close" class="menu-up-control-close">
      <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
    </div>
    <ul class="menu-main">
      <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="menu-footer">
      <div class="item">Footer</div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```